# How to change the Raspberry Pi's hostname (in Raspbmc)?

Tags: networking, raspbmc, kodi

Currently my dhcp-log displays my Raspberry Pi with the name `xbmc-e0cb`. Can I change this to a more sensible name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update the host name in the following files

```
/etc/hostname
/etc/hosts
```

Change the name, and it will change on network-restart (or full reboot, of course).

Updating `/etc/hosts` is necessary to avoid the following error

```
sudo: unable to resolve host <new-hostname>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out that my dhcp would need to be reconfigured if I wanted the Pi also be getting this as a name in my net.

Comment: When I changed the file's contents, and attempted to overwrite the file, I was told that the Pi `Can't open file to write`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you edit it as root or as normal user? Try putting `sudo` in front of your edit-command.

Comment: I did that, and now every time I use sudo it says `sudo: unable to resolve host` and the new name, before it runs the command.

Comment: Ah, found it. Needed to update /etc/hosts as well.

Comment: The contents of my `hostname` file isn't appearing on the network. But I just fixed my ip as per [these instructions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3250/9288), which is probably why.  Any advice?

Comment: No matter what I do, my hostname won't change:

/etc/hostname = raspbmc
/etc/hosts = 127.0.0.1 raspbmc
$ hostname
raspbmc

But my router still picks it up as xbmc-7164.  Any ideas?

Comment: Many sources also point to run `sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh` , e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/167195/how-to-change-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-devices-hostname/ or https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=125373

Answer (score 3):

I did this, adapted from http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=7180

```
sudo nano /scripts/nm_util.py
```

Almost at the bottom of the file, uid is set. Comment out all of the if clause, and change it to

```
uid = "MyHostname"
```

Comment: This doesn't tally with my file. I have `uuid = params['nm.uuid']` at the start of `def deactivate_connection`.  Is that what you refer to?

Comment: @geotheory: he refers to the lines near "uid = "xbmc-"+mac_list[4].lower()+mac_list[5].lower()", but it is a confusing answer (for instance, "almost at the bottom of the file" is actually only 80% down in the file).

Answer (score 2):

Additionally you can change the hostname on the fly by issuing the commang
`sysctl kernel.hostname=NEW_HOSTNAME`. But that is no permanent solution. @René Wolferink already posted the only permanent way.

*hth*

Comment: Nonetheless, thank you for completing the picture and not requiring a reboot. Useful tip way beyond just raspbmc.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of **systemd** (Raspbian Jessie and newer), the prescribed method is finally a single command ([reference](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname#systemd)):

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <mymachine>
```

Changes take effect immediately and persist after reboot.

Comment: I may have posted too soon... this seems to leave `/etc/hosts` in a dismal state